# pandas: how to update a matching row using a dictionary without iterating

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe  :

```
data = [{'car' :'audi','year':2001,'wheel':4},
        {'car' :'honda','year':2002,'wheel':15},
        {'car' :'tesla','year':2003,'wheel':5}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('car',inplace=True)
```

I filter dataframe using a dictionary to get the matching row:

```
filtObj = {'year':2002,'wheel':15}
dfMatched = df.loc[(df[list(filtObj)] == pd.Series(filtObj)).all(axis=1)]
```

Q) Once a match is found, how do I update the match with only those key,value pairs specified in the update dictionary

```
updateObj = {'year':2020}
dfMatched.update(updateObj)
```

Comment: So need `dfMatched = df.loc[(df[list(filtObj)] == pd.Series(filtObj)).all(axis=1)].copy()`  and then `dfMatched.update(pd.DataFrame(updateObj, index=dfMatched.index))` ?

Comment: @jezrael thank you but i need the change updated in the original dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with `DataFrame` created with dictionary and with filtered index for match by mask:

```
filtObj = {'year':2002,'wheel':15}
m = (df[list(filtObj)] == pd.Series(filtObj)).all(axis=1)

updateObj = {'year':2020}
df.update(pd.DataFrame(updateObj, index=df.index[m]))

print (df)
         year  wheel
car                 
audi   2001.0      4
honda  2020.0     15
tesla  2003.0      5
```